# When Nest goes to Google Assistant, how can I use my own C# application, using Firebase, to get and set the temperature status of the Nest

Tags: c#, google-assistant-sdk

At the moment I have my own C# application, using Firebase, to get and set the temperature status of the Nest. However, Nest goes to Google Assistant on 31th August 2019. How can I upgrade my application? Is it possible to communicate with some kind of Google Assistant Service API?

Answer (score 1):

The Google Assistant does not have an API for developers to get the state of devices from other companies.

Comment: That is quite disappointing... Nest was so cool, using Firebase, to be able to get the state of the devices. I wonder why Google is not that open for other companies.